# Implicit Differentiation: cot(r(Θ)^4) = 1/6 ????

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

cot(r(Θ)^4) = 1/6 ---- Solving for dr/dΘ

So I differentiate, and I get -csc^2(r(Θ)^4)(4r(Θ)^3 + (dr/dΘ)(Θ^4)) = 0

farthest point I got to is (-4r(Θ)^3-(dr/dΘ)(Θ^4))/sin^2(r(Θ^4)) = 0

how are you supposed to put anything else on the right hand side when all is being multiplied?

Answer (score 3):

$$\cot(r\theta^4)=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$-\csc^2(r\theta^4)\big(4r\theta^3+\frac{dr}{d\theta}\theta^4\big)=0$$
Notice that $\csc^2(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, so we can divide both sides by it:
$$-(r\theta^4)\big(4r\theta^3+\frac{dr}{d\theta}\theta^4\big)=0$$
Now notice that since
$$\cot(r\theta^4)=\frac{1}{6}$$
it is impossible for $\theta$ to equal $0$. Thus we can divide both sides by $\theta$ as much as we want, and the same goes for $r$:
$$\big(4r\theta^3+\frac{dr}{d\theta}\theta^4\big)=0$$
$$4r+\frac{dr}{d\theta}\theta=0$$
$$\color{green}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-\frac{4r}{\theta}}$$

Comment: how did  you reduce 4rΘ^3 + dr/dΘ(Θ)^4 = 0 to 4r + dr/dΘ(Θ^3) = 0?

Comment: if you divided the left hand side by Θ^3 then wouldn't you get 4r + dr/dΘ(Θ) = 0?

Comment: Yeah you made a typo, the answer was dr/dΘ = -4r/Θ

Comment: @MatthewButner Yep, fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the implicit function $$f=\cot(r\theta^4)-\frac{1}{6}=0$$ and compute the partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=-\theta ^4 \csc ^2\left(r\theta ^4 \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=-4 \theta ^3 r \csc ^2\left(r\theta ^4 \right)$$ and, from the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dr}{d \theta}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} } {\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} }=-\frac{4 r}{\theta }$$